# Spark GMM RDD automatically indexed?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to spark GMM, but I have quite good knowledge on how GMMs work. So I have a question which I hope someone could enlighten me on.

The code I am using is standard Spark mllib GMM, I have a non-indexed RDD called Input in the format of RDD(Value), where the I want the Value to be clustered using the GMM.predictSoft:

```
val Vectorize = Input.map(x=>(Vectors.dense(x)))
val Valuegmm = newGaussianMixture().setK(5).run(Vectorize)
val GMMgroup = Valuegmm.predictSoft(Vectorize).map(x=>x.indexOf(x.max))
```

It question is that in the predictSoft process, the input is the non-indexed vector; as it is an RDD, I expected the index of the output result to be shuffled (i.e. the first result might not be the result of the first input). To my surprise the output results are actually matching the input. Could someone help explain is this Always true or is my test data size too small that I have not experienced a shuffle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for shuffle here. `predictSoft` is map-only operation where relevant parts of the model are simply broadcasted to the worker nodes. It means that both partition membership and order per partition should be preserved.

Generally speaking shuffle occurs only during combine-by transformations (like `groupBy`, `combineByKey`, `foldByKey`, `reduceByKey`, `join`, etc.), partitioning and sorting.